# Different output for 'run' and 'debug' when using readline()

Tags: java, netbeans

I get two different output for the same code. I get one result when I debug and step through every line (using Netbeans 8.1). And I get a different result when I run the code all at once.

This is the code,

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
        String str = file.readLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This is the input file

```
first
second
third
fourth
```

The code should print the first line `first` in both cases. But it does that only when I run the code.

If I debug the code and step through every line, the second line `second` is printed.

Why is this happening?

**Update:**
The following is a debugging screenshot. Right now, if I step over it will execute the System.out.println line. As you can see on the right side, str contains 'second'.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen every time? Or intermittently?

Comment: @Kon It happens every time.

Comment: What utility are you using to debug-step through your code?

Comment: @snickers10m Netbean 8.1 default debugging tool.

Comment: Are you sure you only have a breakpoint inside your `main` method?

Comment: @Kon Yes. I am debugging from this line "BufferedReader file..."

Comment: I debugged here in Intellij and it prints `first` as expected. Your behavior is awkward indeed.

Comment: I've also tested on Eclipse with JDK 8 and it works as expected with/without debugger. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, or even restarting your debugger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does your IDE evaluate `file.readLine()` while you are debugging? In Eclipse, one can define “watch expressions” that do exactly this.

This might explain your problem, since when you step through the code line by line, there is exactly one line in which `file` is defined and therefore the expression above can be evaluated. Therefore the output of `second` instead of `first`.

*Update:* Now that you added the screenshot, it’s clear. It’s partly the Netbean developer’s fault, since they chose “Variables” at the headline, which is misleading, since evaluating variables does not have a side-effect, while evaluating arbitrary expressions (like `file.readLine()`) clearly has.

Comment: I could replicate it! Just stop at the `file.readLine()` and enable a watcher for it and the sysout will print the second line. That is new to me

Comment: Perhaps this is one case of the debugger causing a side effect by evaluating the expression file.readLine() which is indeed shown in the watchlist in that screenshot. So Rolland is right, that should be the root cause.

Comment: You are correct. The problem goes away when I remove file.readLine() from the 'Variable' list. Perhaps it's time to submit an enhancement request on netbeans portal.

Comment: So how do I watch file.readLine()? I tried to add it to "Watch" tab, but the side efffect is still there.

Comment: You cannot watch `file.readLine()` without executing it each time; and then you get the side-effects. So the only possible way is to use variables for that: `String line = file.readLine();`—watching this variable doesn’t break anything.

Comment: The same goes for IntelliJ Idea.